# How to write complex Typescript object in Angular HTML attribute

Tags: angular

How does one write HTML to populate a complex `@Input` parameter in Angular?

---

If I have an Angular Component like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-one',
  templateUrl: './one.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./one.component.css']
})
export class OneComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() data: MyCustomType;
...

export class MyCustomType {
  id: string;
  value: number;
}
```

Can I write HTML to populate it?
Something in the lines of:

```
<app-my data="{'id':'a','value':1}></app-my>
```

There is no problem populating it through Typescript, as is the normal case, but in this case I want to populate it from HTML alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use data binding syntax like so:

```
<app-my [data]="{'id':'a','value':1}"></app-my>
```

When using this syntax you can do various javascript operations, e.g. creating object, calling methods etc. Of course only with what is available on component class.